# MongoDB update field only if cursor has field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I am updating MongoDB document using a cursor loop. But in the below query cursor ***owner*** field cannot exist in the results. I am using below query but looks like results.hasOwnProperty('owner') always returning true and it is throwing error results.owner doesn't exists.

Even I tried db.contact_coolection.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5b876144d87b4d06ecb571b8")}) --> This gives ownerCRMContactId.$cond is not valid.

I think $cond is aggregator operator, what should be used in this case?

```
db.contact_coolection.find().forEach(function(results)
{    
    print( "Id: " + results._id);
    db.contact_coolection.update( {_id : results._id},
    {$set : {
        "ownerCRMContactId": {
                 $cond: { if: results.hasOwnProperty('owner'), then: results.owner.$id, else: '' }
               }
        }
     });
});
```

Below is the sample document doesn't containing owner

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b876144d87b4d06ecb571b8"),
    "_class" : "com.cfcf.crm.model.auth.CRMContact",
    "crmId" : -09898,
    "prefix" : "Mr",
    "firstName" : "fghh",
    "middleName" : "asdgasd",
    "lastName" : "asdasd",
    "suffix" : "asdassd",
    "nickName" : "asdasd",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "age" : "0",
    "dlNumber" : "0",
    "height" : 0,
    "weight" : 0,
    "isSmoker" : false,
    "deleted" : false,
    "isEnabled" : false,
    "externalSource" : [],
    "familyMembers" : [],
    "crmInfos" : [ 
        {
            "opportunityId" : "5b95fa6c28e76b60c0454a2e"
        }
    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-08-30T03:15:16.181Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T05:00:28.627Z"),
    "createdBy" : "5b2f43e433d58d3e0cd15304",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "5b2f43e433d58d3e0cd15304",
    "owner" : {
        "$ref" : "contact_coolection",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5b2f43e433d58d3e0cd15303")
    },
    "roles" : [],
    "links" : [ 
        {
            "linkId" : 0,
            "linkTitle" : "testsLinkss",
            "linkUrl" : "www.google.com"
        }
    ],
    "addresses" : [ 
        {
            "addressLine1" : "3rd Cross",
            "addressLine2" : "Kensington Street",
            "city" : "Birmingham",
            "state" : "Alabama",
            "country" : "US"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way

```
const promises = db.contact_coolection.find().forEach(async(results) => {
  print( "Id: " + results._id);
  await db.contact_coolection.update(
    { _id: results._id },
    { $set: {
      ownerCRMContactId: results.owner ? results.owner.$id : ''
    }}
  )
})

await Promise.all(promises)
```

**Update**

```
const promises = db.contact_coolection.find().forEach(async(results) => {
  print( "Id: " + results._id);
  await db.contact_coolection.update(
    { _id: results._id },
    { $set: {
      ownerCRMContactId: (results && results.owner) ? results.owner.$id : ''
    }}
  )
})

await Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Can I skip setting if results.owner doesn't exists? If yes how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean you do want to run query if `result.owner` doesn't exists?

Comment: Can this be done using the ternary operator or single line as before? because I have other fields to set. don't want to write too many if blocks.

Comment: Thanks. but it is setting value as '' not same as not setting the field. What is the null equivalent in MongoDB?

Comment: Then you have to go with the if else condition